# VBA copies content from each file in the folder to the corresponding worksheet in the master workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help on the following code, basically i have about 50 excel files in a folder and i want to copy data from each excel file to the master file. There are 3 worksheets in each file with the name 6D6 Cash, 6D6 Position and 6D6 Transactions and masterworkbook also has those tabs so for example macro will copy all the data from 6D6 cash worksheet in each excel file to the 6D6 cash worksheet in the master workbook and the new data will go below the last filled row. Also the row in each excel file has the header so that won't go in obviously.

For some reason, it's not working, as in the code is not working at all. What could be the reason?

```
Sub Adam1()
Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wsDst As Worksheet
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim lLastRow As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wbDst = ThisWorkbook

MyPath = "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\6D6 files"
strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls*", vbNormal)

Do While strFilename <> ""

        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & strFilename)

        'loop through each worksheet in the source file
        For Each wsSrc In wbSrc.Worksheets
            'Find the corresponding worksheet in the destination with the same name as the source
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wsDst = wbDst.Worksheets(wsSrc.Name)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If wsDst.Name = wsSrc.Name Then
                lLastRow = wsDst.UsedRange.Rows(wsDst.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1
                wsSrc.UsedRange.Copy
                wsDst.Range("A" & lLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        Next wsSrc

        wbSrc.Close False
        strFilename = Dir()
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with what isn't working? "It doesn't work" can range from your computer is not turned on to a piece of bad coding. I would hazard a guess that there is an issue opening the files but with `DisplayAlerts` disable you would never know. Enable those three things and step through the code using F8 to see what its doing.

Comment: Apparently there's a break somewhere. The yellow highlighted part skips the parts after Do While and goes straight to Application.DisplayAlerts at the end

Comment: There's no highlighted part. Just doesn't run. When i press F8, it stops at Do while, skips the part underneath and goes to the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an incomplete string.

```
MyPath = "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\6D6 files" 
strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls*", vbNormal)
```

Will be returning C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\6D6 filessomefile.xls

```
MyPath = "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\6D6 files\"  'with the extra slash
strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls*", vbNormal)
```

Comment: Yeah, this works. Next error is  If wsDst.Name = wsSrc.Name Then  --- do you know why it gets stuck here?

Comment: Need to be more specific, does it just skip this line or is there an error?